# My version of a solution to the infamous Euler Number 3 C#

Tags: c#

I apologize for my recent post, where I was unclear, did minimal research, and violated some of the website's rules. Therefore I am uploading a new version of a practically working code, except for a single problem. My return on this code is "1" and not the result, which I am looking for : the greatest prime factor of "600851475143". Here is the revised and hopefully more understandable code. Once again, I am very sorry for having violated the policy of the website.

```
public long Prob_3()
    {
        long a = 600851475143;
        int e = 1;
        for (long i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (a % 2 == 0 && a != 1)
            {
                a = a / 2;
            }
            else if (a % 2 != 0 && a % (e + 2) == 0 && a != 1)
            {
                a = a / (e + 2);
            }
            while (a % 2 != 0 && a % (e + 2) != 0 && a != 1)
            {
                e = e + 2;
            }

        }
        return a;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but "Please fix this for me" questions are off-topic for this site. Even if they weren't, the least you could do is use descriptive variable names.

Comment: Really strange question - there are plenty working solutions for the problem, but you are asking *others* to fix your code (which you explicitly made non-readable for some reasons - "...it's kind of a mess")... Answer to your question - use existing solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is correct, but you are not returning the greatest prime factor of `600851475143`; you are dividing it by itself right before you return it! To "fix" your code, all I did was add the following commented line in the body of `Prob_3`:

```
long a = 600851475143;
int e = 1;
for (long i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (a % 2 == 0 && a != 1)
    {
        a = a / 2;
    }
    else if (a % 2 != 0 && a % (e + 2) == 0 && a != 1)
    {
        if (a / (e + 2) == 1) break; // !
        a = a / (e + 2);
    }
    while (a % 2 != 0 && a % (e + 2) != 0 && a != 1)
    {
        e = e + 2;
    }

}
return a;
```

What it does is simply act as a base case.

Comment: I really appreciate it although it is my fault for being unclear in the request. I am a relatively entry level programmer, at least in c#. I have solved the 1st and easiest Euler problem, but found myself stuck on this one. I just wanted to see what I was doing incorrectly in terms of my code. But, since it was a complete mess I have uploaded a newer version of my code with a (hopefully) more clearer request and more understandable code.

Comment: @user2643689, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I appreciate your help very much. You have been very helpful. Thank you. +1